# How to upload cPanel Backup to VPS

Tags: vps

1. I am a COMPLETE NOOB in coding or VPS ETC, I know absolutely nothing. I had a web hosting package but I have now moved to a VPS because they can hold more people and my site has a bot which can only be used automatically on a VPS. I have a cPanel backup file/folder with everything needed, and what I want to do is just somehow re upload EVERYTHING the way it was before. Please help >_<

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not server related questions. Flagged for closure.

Answer (score 0):

When both of your web servers have cPanel installed, the best method would be cPanel to cPanel account migration. You'll have to run "copy an account" wizard from your VPS' WHM. WHM will fetch the backups of your cPanel accounts from shared server and restore them to VPS automatically. Refer to following articles for step by step guidance.

[Move accounts from one cPanel server to other](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/921/How-to-Move-Accounts-From-One-cPanel-Server-To-Another-.html)